# Using Excel to extract information from files

Tags: excel

I'm new here and I'm hoping someone can help me.  I have an Excel file that contains code names for clients in column A.  I also have a folder with .xml files that are named with those code names that are in Column A in the Excel file.

What I need is for Excel to search for the file that matches the code in cell **A1**, and extract certain information from that file.  Then I need it to proceed to cell **B1** and do the same for the code it finds there.  Does anyone know how to make this happen?  Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You'll be wanting to loop through each file in a folder.  Here's a [search to get you started](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=vba%20get%20names%20of%20files%20in%20folder), or [this page](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=65530) too.

Comment: Thank you!  I do know how to retrieve a list of named files in a folder but what I need, if possible, is for Excel to find a particular name in the folder by finding it's match from a particular cell and once it finds that name, I need it to copy certain information from it and place into a different spreadsheet.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty simple `If` statement would work. When looping through each file, do something like `If myFile.name Like Cells(1,1).Value Then ...`?  (maybe `like` isn't the best, but basically you want to see if the file name is similar to cell A1 (or whatever you want)).

Answer (score -1):

You want to start with the following code:

```
Dim filename as String
Dim idx as integer
idx = 65
while idx < 92
    col = char(idx)
    filename = Dir(Sheets(1).Range(col + "1").Value)
    While filename <> ""
        process file
        filename = Dir
    Wend
    idx = idx 1
wend
```

Comment: note that if you will need to include the full folder path in the initial Dir command if it isn't in the cell.

Answer (score -1):

In your comment, you state the following:

> I do know how to retrieve a list of named files in a folder but what I
>   need, if possible, is for Excel to find a particular name in the
>   folder by finding it's match from a particular cell and once it finds
>   that name, I need it to copy certain information from it and place
>   into a different spreadsheet

Here is some basic code that demonstrates how to do what you're looking for.  It is commented for clarity and to make it easier for you to customize.

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rName As Range
    Dim sFldrPath As String
    Dim sFileName As String

    'Change to correct folder path
    'Be sure to include ending \
    sFldrPath = "C:\Test\"

    'Change to correct workbook if necessary.
    'In most cases ActiveWorkbook will be what you want
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    'Change to correct worksheet that contains the list of names
    Set wsData = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Change to correct destination worksheet where you will output results
    Set wsDest = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")

    'Change to correct range that contains the list of names
    'This example assumes header row is row 1, actual data starts in row 2, names are in column A
    With wsData.Range("A2", wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        If .Row < 2 Then Exit Sub   'First row is prior to the row that should contain data
                                    'This means there is no data in the specified range, so exit out

        'Begin iterating over the names in the range
        For Each rName In .Cells
            'Get the xml file where the name matches vName
            sFileName = Dir(sFldrPath & "*" & CStr(rName.Text) & "*.xml")

            'Did it find a matching file?
            If Len(sFileName) > 0 Then
                '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                '                                 '
                '  Match Found, process the file  '
                '                                 '
                '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

                'Change this to whatever it is you actually want to do
                wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = sFldrPath & sFileName

            End If

        Next rName  'Advance the loop to the next name in the array
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!  I will give this a try.

Comment: I tried this and made the changes in the code but it only adds the file path name to the destination worksheet, then does nothing else that I can see.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Sil Please create a new question.  In the new question, be sure to post your *modified* code along with what you are trying to get it to do.  The code posted here is simply example code to get you started.